# Problem with tikz-dependency

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys, dependencies

I've download the tikz-dependency package and tried the basic example as in the package docs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{tikz-dependency}

\begin{document}
\begin{dependency}
\begin{deptext}
My \& dog \& also \& likes \& eating \& sausage \\
\end{deptext}
\depedge{2}{1}{poss}
\depedge{4}{2}{nsubj}
\depedge{4}{3}{advmod}
\depedge{4}{5}{xcomp}
\depedge{5}{6}{dobj}
\end{dependency}

\end{document}
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

> ! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/depgraph/.search
>   also' and I a m going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

What is wrong?!

**Update**:

The list of files

```
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
    tikz.sty    2008/02/13 v2.00 (rcs-revision 1.27)
     pgf.sty    2008/01/15 v2.00 (rcs-revision 1.12)
  pgfrcs.sty    2008/02/20 v2.00 (rcs-revision 1.21)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2008/01/15 v2.00 (rcs-revision 1.6)
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2009/08/28 v1.8 graphics configuration of TeX Live
   dvips.def    1999/02/16 v3.0i Driver-dependant file (DPC,SPQR)
  pgfsys.sty    2008/02/07 v2.00 (rcs-revision 1.31)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2008/01/23  (rcs-revision 1.6)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v2.00 (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v2.00 (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2007/11/07 v2.00 (rcs-revision 1.8)
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
tikz-dependency.sty    2011/01/08 v1.1 Macros to draw dependency trees
 environ.sty    2008/06/18 v0.2 A new way to define environments
```

**Solution:**
Package update. Thanks to Ulrike Fischer

Comment: Your example works fine for me. Add \listfiles to the document, compile and then post the list of versions from the log-file.

Comment: Thank you Ulrike. Updated the post with the list of versions.

Comment: Your tikz versions are much older than mine. I have e.g. `tikz.sty    2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). If updating your packages does not help, please let us know by updating the question.

Comment: Thank you Ulrike and Peter. I've updated the tikz package and it is working fine now. Much appreciated.